# React warning for Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, semantic-ui-react

I am very beginner in react and i got stacked with a warning, I can not resolve them even i read a lot about it in the internet.

The warning is:

[image]

The App.tsx relevant code parts:

```
  const [selectedMoment, setSelectedMoment] = useState<IMoment | null>(null);

  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

  const handleOpenCreateForm = () => {
      setSelectedMoment(null);
      setEditMode(true);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <NavBar openCreateForm={handleOpenCreateForm} />
    </Fragment>);
```

The menu is in the NavBar.tsx:

```
interface IProps {
    openCreateForm: () => void;
}

export const NavBar: React.FC<IProps> = ({ openCreateForm }) => {
    return (
        <Menu fixed='top' inverted>
            <Container>

                <Menu.Item>
                    <Button positive content="Moment upload" onClick={openCreateForm} />
                </Menu.Item>

            </Container>
        </Menu>
    )
}
```

They are semantic-ui-react elements.
Anybody idea why do i get this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is considered legacy, the alternative API is [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

**Here’s a sample of what the old method would look like:**

```
class List extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.selected !== this.props.selected) {
      this.setState({ selected: nextProps.selected });
      this.selectNew();
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

**The new method works a bit differently:**

```
class List extends React.Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.selected !== state.selected) {
      return {
        selected: props.selected,
      };
    }

    // Return null if the state hasn't changed
    return null;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: i am sorry i am very new in react and it does not help enough to fix my code. Can you be a lit a bit more specific?

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated on new versions and replaced with `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Comment: but i do not use it in my code :D how can i exchange it? The components are from semantic-ui

Comment: Which version using?

Comment: It's an open issue on their repository [UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in Visibility Component](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3919)

Comment: thank you very much, i expected it is coming from my side not from them :D but it is good to know i just need to wait